# Javascript Browser Cache even using querystring after filename

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have an application using **VueJS** and **Webpack**.
I was having a lot of problems with my clients, and at the end, it was just cache. So I always had to tell them "Hey, just clear your cache and everything is going be right"
My webpack generates a `main.js` file. So I had to use a plugin to put a random string after my `main.js` file. The output file is something like: `main.a871nd918.js`. It always different  and it always change. But the problem with cache still there even using random strings after my `.js` file. What is going on?

Thanks for now! =)

Comment: What do you think a query string is?  No part of `main.a871nd918.js` is a query string.

Comment: It might be due to service worker that generates pwa application. Had similar case in react and nothing changed when reloading cache. Only after deleting app cache manually. In create react app..

Comment: Hmm... I'm not working with service workers, it's just a simple `index.html` and `main.js` appication. It works fine just when I force to clean the cache using `ctrl`+`shift`+`r` . But thanks for answer @Sgedda :)

Comment: is it because your index.html is cached?

Comment: Hmm I don't know... Actually my index.html file is also changed every build. Because he had to update the `<script>`reference of my new `.js` file.

Comment: Please show all related requests and responses including HTTP headers. Use Chrome DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy).